# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization and serialize

Tags: json, polymorphism, deserialization

I will two different types of in separate calls. I want to deserialize or serialize depending on the business requirement.

one type of json:

```
{
  "type": "foo",
  "data": [{
    "someCommonProperty": "common property",
    "fooProperty": "foo specific property"
  },{
    "someCommonProperty": "common property1",
    "fooProperty": "foo specific property1"
  }]
}
```

Another type of json:

```
{
  "type": "bar",
  "data": [{
    "someCommonProperty": "common property",
    "barProperty": "bar specific property",
    "type": "type1"
  },{
    "someCommonProperty": "common property1",
    "barProperty": "bar specific property1",
    "type": "type1"
  }]
}
```

I have classes as below

```
 public class Parent {

    private String type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = { 
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "foo"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "bar") 
    })
    private List<AbstractData> data;

    // Getters and setters
 }

 public abstract class AbstractData {

    private String someCommonProperty;

    // Getters and setters
 }

 public class Foo extends AbstractData {

    private String fooProperty;

    // Getters and setters
 }

 public class Bar extends AbstractData {

    private String barProperty;
    private String type;
    // Getters and setters
 }
```

When I try to deserialize as below, I am getting empty string on writing out java object as json.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Parent parent = mapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
```

I get this error:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class com.DemoJsonToJavaDeserialize.AbstractData
 at [Source: C:<projectpath>\target\classes\foo.json; line: 3, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.DemoJsonToJavaDeserialize.Parent["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Option 1

If you have access to the `AbstractData` class, you might want to use the new 2.12 Jackson *Deduction* feature :

```java
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class)
})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
public abstract class AbstractData {
    private String someCommonProperty;
   
   // getters setters
}
```

Then, no need to annotate `Foo`, `Bar` and `Parent` : everything will get instantiated automagically as long as your subclasses have different property names. `type` json property becomes useless as well.

(If you are using SpringBoot, you can set the `jackson-bom.version` property to upgrade jackson inside spring boot)

#### Option 2

the *javadoc* of `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` says : `Note also that this mechanism can not be used for container values (arrays, Collections...` . I believe this is your problem: you're applying it to a `List`.

If you can't modify any of the Foo/Barr/AbstractData classes, the classic way is to use a custom *Deserializer*.
On the `Parent` class :

```
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = FooBarDeserializer.class)
    private List<AbstractData> data;
```

And the Deserializer:

```
public class FooBarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<AbstractData> {
    @Override
    public AbstractData deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        if(node.has("fooProperty"))
            return jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node,Foo.class);
        else
            return jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node,Bar.class);
    }
}
```

If you find a solution that make use of your `Parent.type` , please share, I'm interested.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted yours as answer. I did end up writing custom Deserializer but your is more elegant than my implementation.

Comment: The first option worked for me. Thanks